# suphp error Directory / is not owned by admin

Tags: apache-2.2, php, httpd, php5, suphp

I'm trying to run a test phpinfo page from:

/home/admin/testdomain.com

But it displays such error:

```
Internal Server Error

Directory / is not owned by admin
suPHP 0.7.1
```

My /etc/suphp.conf is like this:

```
[global]
logfile=/var/log/httpd/suphp_log
loglevel=info
webserver_user=apache
docroot=/
env_path=/bin:/usr/bin
umask=0022
min_uid=500
min_gid=48

; Security options
allow_file_group_writeable=true
allow_file_others_writeable=false
allow_directory_group_writeable=true
allow_directory_others_writeable=false

;Check wheter script is within DOCUMENT_ROOT
check_vhost_docroot=false

;Send minor error messages to browser
errors_to_browser=true

[handlers]
;Handler for php-scripts
x-httpd-php="php:/usr/bin/php-cgi"
; x-httpd-php52="php:/usr/local/lxlabs/ext/php/bin/php_cgi"
x-httpd-php52="php:/usr/local/lxlabs/ext/php/etc/lxphpcgi.sh"

;Handler for CGI-scripts
x-suphp-cgi="execute:!self"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix is simple:

```
chown root.root /
```

Comment: First thanks a lot, the fix is indeed easy and quick! How come it happens? Why should the / permissions change? And why SuPHP talks about "not owned by user" while the / has to be owned by root ?

Comment: I don't know but it works ok ;)

Comment: Cooool!!! But... why chown root.root / has resolved the problem? tell me, please :-D

Comment: Please up my answer ;)